# ImportError: No module named cms when running Django with django-cms installed

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I had a local working django project based on django–cms. Now suddenly its not working anymore when i activate virtualenv `source env/bin/activate` and runserver `python manage.py runserver` i get `ImportError: No module named cms`.
Here full Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named cms
```

I dont understand this because everything allways worked fine only thing i did 2 weeks ago was to put the directory where the project lives in away from my desktop to another location. 
Anyone knows how to fix this or whats the reason for that.

pip list:

```
argparse (1.3.0)
binaryornot (0.3.0)
cookiecutter (0.8.0)
coverage (3.7.1)
distribute (0.7.3)
dj-database-url (0.3.0)
Django (1.7.1)
django-allauth (0.18.0)
django-appconf (0.6)
django-autoslug (1.7.2)
django-avatar (2.0)
django-braces (1.4.0)
django-cache-url (0.8.0)
django-classy-tags (0.4)
django-configurations (0.8)
django-crispy-forms (1.4.0)
django-debug-toolbar (1.2.2)
django-extensions (1.4.9)
django-floppyforms (1.3.0)
django-front (0.4.3)
django-inplaceedit (1.3.0)
django-model-utils (2.2)
django-mptt (0.6.0)
django-reversion (1.8.0)
django-secure (1.0.1)
django-sekizai (0.7)
django-wymeditor (1.0)
djangocms-admin-style (0.2.0)
djangocms-installer (0.7.2)
djangocms-text-ckeditor (2.0.5)
docutils (0.12)
html5lib (1.0b1)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
mock (1.0.1)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
oauthlib (0.7.2)
Pillow (2.6.1)
pip (1.5.6)
psycopg2 (2.5.4)
Pygments (2.0.1)
python-openid (2.2.5)
pytz (2013.8)
PyYAML (3.11)
requests (2.5.1)
requests-oauthlib (0.4.2)
setuptools (8.0)
six (1.4.1)
South (0.8.4)
Sphinx (1.2.3)
sqlparse (0.1.14)
unicode-slugify (0.1.1)
virtualenv (12.0.5)
waitress (0.8.9)
Werkzeug (0.9.6)
whitenoise (1.0.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

Comment: After activating the virtualenv.. if you run `pip list` command .. what do you get?

Comment: I can't see `cms` in that list. You'll need to reinstall  `django-cms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving your virtualenv will break it because it uses an absolute path. If you moved the folder that has the virtualenv in it, then the path will no longer point to the virtualenv's packages. You need to either put the virtualenv where it was before or make a new virtualenv.

Comment: ok many thanks. I finally got it… Problem was Virtualenv's have an absolute Path. I got it by  `printenv`. Afterwards i typed `virtualenv env` which replaced the old path with the actual one.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I added a little to the first sentence to make it more helpful. If you want to add anything to clarify or add your steps for recovering, please edit this answer for the next person who comes along.